# Using OpenCV Python, How would you make all black pixels transparent, and then overlay it over original image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to make a colored mask, white.
And my idea is to:

- make black pixels transparent in the mask
- merge the two images
- crop images

so then my original masked area will be white.
What kind of OpenCV python code/methods would I need?

Like so:

Original

[image: Original]

Mask

[image: Mask]

Desired result (mocked up - no green edges)

[image: Desired result (mocked up - no green edges)]

Instead of

[image: Instead of]

Comment: Could you post how you are getting the mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose to do a color threshold  to get the mask itself.
The result I got in a first quick and dirty attempt with Hue 43-81, Saturation 39-197 and Brightness from 115-255 is:
[image]

The next step is a whole fill algorithm to fill the inside of the mask. Note that also one small area to the right is selected.

[image]

The next step is a substraction of the two results (mask-filled_mask):

[image]

Again fill the wholes and get rid of the noisy pixels with binary opening:

[image]

Last mask the image with the created mask.

[image]

Every step can be adjusted to yield optimal results. A good idea is to try the steps out (for example with imageJ) to get your workflow set up and then script the steps in python/openCV.

Refer also to http://fiji.sc/Segmentation.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your mask is a boolean numpy array and your 2 images are numpy arrays image1 and image2.

Then you can use the boolean array as multiplier.

```
overlay= mask*image1 + (-mask)*image2
```

So you get the "True" pixels from image1 and the False pixels from image2